# Creating a deltatime array in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am new to python, so I decided to start a project to improve my skills. Therefore, I started trying [this one on GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracking-bird-migration-using-python-3/). Now, I am having difficulty to append a deltaTime variable into an array. I tried a numpy array as well, but it did not worked out.

My code:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import Formatter
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np
from pandas._libs.tslibs import timestamps

birdData = pd.read_csv("bird_tracking.csv")
birdNames = pd.unique(birdData.bird_name)

#Pegando intervalo do tempo
timestamps = []
for i in range(len(birdData)):
    timestamps.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(birdData.date_time.iloc[i][:-3], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

birdData["timestamps"] = pd.Series(timestamps, index = birdData.index)

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))

for name in birdNames:
    times = birdData.timestamps[birdData.bird_name == name]
    elapsedTime = []
    for time in times:
        x = time-times[0]
        #print(x)
        elapsedTime.append(x)

    plt.plot(np.array(elapsedTime)/datetime.timedelta(days=1), label = name)

plt.xlabel(" Observation ")
plt.ylabel(" Elapsed time (days) ")

plt.show()
```

The error that I am finding:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
    File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1625, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
    File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1632, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\TrackingBirdMigration\dataTime.py", line 24, in <module>
x = time-times[0]
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
return self._get_value(key)
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 961, in _get_value
loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0

[Done] exited with code=1 in 8.313 seconds
```

Comment: I think you want: `times = birdData.loc[birdData.bird_name == name, 'timestamps']`

Comment: also maybe: `elapsedTime = (times - times.shift()).fillna(0)`